# iOS PDF Kit - Full Size Page

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I want to create a pdf document with full size page. It doesn't fill the whole page. How can I fix it.

```
class PDFAssortmentExporter: NSObject {
        
    var metaDataPDF: PDFMetaData
    lazy var pageWidth : CGFloat  = {
        return 11 * 72.0
    }()

    lazy var pageHeight : CGFloat = {
        return 8.5 * 72.0
    }()

    lazy var pageRect : CGRect = {
        CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight)
    }()

    lazy var marginPoint : CGPoint = {
        return CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
    }()

    lazy var marginSize : CGSize = {
        return CGSize(width: self.marginPoint.x * 2 , height: self.marginPoint.y * 2)
    }()
    
    init(metaDataPDF: PDFMetaData) {
        self.metaDataPDF = metaDataPDF
    }
    
    func prepareData() -> Data {
        
        let pdfMetaData = [
            kCGPDFContextCreator: metaDataPDF.contextCreatorPDF,
            kCGPDFContextAuthor: metaDataPDF.authorPDF,
            kCGPDFContextTitle: metaDataPDF.contextTitle
        ]

        let format = UIGraphicsPDFRendererFormat() 
        format.documentInfo = pdfMetaData as [String: Any]
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: pageRect, format: format)

        
        let data = renderer.pdfData { (context) in

        }
        
        return data
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you displaying the pdf using PDFView?

Comment: Yes, displaying it using PDFView. Following this tutorial

https://www.raywenderlich.com/4023941-creating-a-pdf-in-swift-with-pdfkit

Comment: Change the displayMode to single page, `pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the displayMode to single page for pdfView

```
pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
pdfView.autoScales = true
//pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it, Didn't work